# org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Invalid capabilities using DesiredCapabilities

Tags: java, selenium, iedriverserver, desiredcapabilities, mutablecapabilities

I have upgraded my Selenium framework to the latest version. During execution of the code, I receive the following exception:

**Exception:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: 
Invalid capabilities in alwaysMatch: unhandledPromptBehavior is type boolean instead of string
```

Details:

- Selenium: 3.7.1;
- IE: 3.7.0 (32 Bit Driver);
- java.version: '1.8.0_144'.

Also newer version suggests `driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);` is deprecated. I am setting capabilities of the browser separately in a function and passing it as a parameter in Driver.

How to resolve this issue?

Code snippet:

```
desiredCapabilities(browser);

IE Capabilities Setting:- 
capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities().internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_ALERTS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOR, true);
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_ELEMENT_CACHE_CLEANUP, true);
capabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
capabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", false);
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
capabilities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", ieExe.getAbsolutePath());
```

Then I invoke my driver:

```
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: Can you show us your code trials and what you are passing through `setting capabilities`?

Comment: Before setting browser I invoke function desiredCapabilities(browser);             Below are the capabilities used to set the browser

Comment: And what is the defination of `browser`and `desiredCapabilities`?

Comment: Code snippet  added in the question. Browser and Desired Capabilities are the functions used in my framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the **`Selenium`** implementation from **`v3.7`** on wards no more accepts `DesiredCapabilities` type objects as a parameter to initialize `Web Browser` instances rather only strongly typed `Options` classes are preferred. So you have to use **`InternetExplorerOptions`** Class object, use **`merge`** argument from **`MutableCapabilities`** and pass as a parameter. Your code block will be as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS", true);
capabilities.setCapability("ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS", true);
capabilities.setCapability("SUPPORTS_ALERTS", true);
capabilities.setCapability("UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOR", true);
capabilities.setCapability("IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION", true);
capabilities.setCapability("ENABLE_ELEMENT_CACHE_CLEANUP", true);
capabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
capabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", false);
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
capabilities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
InternetExplorerOptions opt = new InternetExplorerOptions();
opt.merge(capabilities);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(opt);
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try to implement and let you know

Comment: Capabilities issue is resolved. But I am still facing the error org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: 
Invalid capabilities in alwaysMatch: unhandledPromptBehavior is type boolean instead of string

Comment: Can you raise a new question with the exact error `InvalidArgumentException: Invalid capabilities in alwaysMatch: unhandledPromptBehavior` and `desiredCapabilities(browser);`

Comment: Yes raised separate question for the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47410707/invalid-capabilities-in-alwaysmatch-unhandledpromptbehavior-is-type-boolean-ins