# Invalid capabilities in alwaysMatch: unhandledPromptBehavior is type boolean instead of string

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-iedriver, desiredcapabilities, mutablecapabilities

I have upgraded my Selenium framework to the latest version. During execution of the code, I receive the following exception

**Exception**:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: 
Invalid capabilities in alwaysMatch: unhandledPromptBehavior is type boolean instead of string
```

**Details :**

Selenium: 3.7.1
IE : 3.7.0 (32 Bit Driver)
java.version: '1.8.0_144'

Automation code works with my older IE Driver (32 Bit) - 3.4.0.

Please suggest your view to resolve the error .

```
capabilities.setCapability("UNHANDLED_PROMPT_BEHAVIOUR" ,false);
                    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
                    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
                    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_ALERTS, true);
                    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOR, true);
                    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
                    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_ELEMENT_CACHE_CLEANUP, true);
                    capabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
                    capabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", false);
                    capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
                    capabilities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", ieExe.getAbsolutePath());
                    opt = new InternetExplorerOptions();
                    opt.merge(capabilities);
                    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(opt);
                    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: Can you share your code block relating to `unhandledPromptBehavior`?

Comment: Added code for your reference

Comment: I don't see the `unhandledPromptBehavior` attribute in your code. Am I missing something?

Comment: Modified the code snippet

Answer (score 3):

***In short:***

- Valid capability name is: `"unhandledPromptBehavior"`
- Valid values for `"unhandledPromptBehavior"` AND for `"unexpectedAlertBehavior"`  are: `"accept"`, `"dismiss"`, `"accept and notify"`, `"dismiss and notify"`, `"ignore"`. But W3C supports [only 1st and 2nd](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-known-prompt-handling-approaches-table).

***In details:***

UNHANDLED_PROMPT_BEHAVIOUR is a constant name from `CapabilityType` interface. But you use it as string. So either `capabilities.setCapability("unhandledPromptBehavior", ...)` or `capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNHANDLED_PROMPT_BEHAVIOUR, ...)`

Values for those capabilities are encauntered in enum `org.openqa.selenium.UnexpectedAlertBehaviour`: it is because `unhandledPromptBehavior` is new updated name for `unexpectedAlertBehaviour` in webdriver3. Actually when you set *unexpectedAlertBehaviour* the webdriver (v3.8) automatically [set both values](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/80adb709873815b88bb57494a6908f8b86285766/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/AbstractCapabilities.java#L91).

So root cause of your error is the line:
`capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOR, true)`:

You should replace `true` to valid value (see above). This line actually set both capabilities: `unhandledPromptBehavior` and `unexpectedAlertBehaviour`. Your first line (with "UNHANDLED_PROMPT_BEHAVIOR") just ignored by driver.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue with below change
"capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);"

Answer (score 0):

The error `InvalidArgumentException: Invalid capabilities in alwaysMatch: unhandledPromptBehavior is type boolean instead of string Details` says does speaks about the main issue.

As you mentioned `IE Driver` so I guess the issue is with **`Internet Explorer`** and **`IEDriverServer.exe`**. To over come the issue use `setCapability("UNHANDLED_PROMPT_BEHAVIOUR", "accept")` as per the following code block :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("UNHANDLED_PROMPT_BEHAVIOUR", "accept");
InternetExplorerOptions opt = new InternetExplorerOptions();
opt.merge(capabilities);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(opt);
```

Comment: I tried the same and its still showing the same error.

Comment: Try changing it to `"UNHANDLED_PROMPT_BEHAVIOUR", false`

Comment: Still getting same error : [ERROR] 2017-11-22 11:36:41.384 [main] DetailedLogs - Error : >>>>>Class Keywords | Method setupBrowser | Exception desc : Invalid capabilities in alwaysMatch: unhandledPromptBehavior is type boolean instead of string
Build info: version: '3.7.0', revision: '2321c73', time: '2017-11-02T22:22:35.584Z'
System info: host: 'EQ-EQ6338424', ip: '10.238.214.158', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver

Comment: Even I modifed code as you mentioned capabilities.setCapability("UNHANDLED_PROMPT_BEHAVIOUR" ,false);

Comment: Try this : `capabilities.setCapability("UNHANDLED_PROMPT_BEHAVIOUR", Boolean.parseBoolean("true"));` and `capabilities.setCapability("UNHANDLED_PROMPT_BEHAVIOUR", Boolean.parseBoolean("false"));`

Comment: Same error. I modified my code as below                                                              capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNHANDLED_PROMPT_BEHAVIOUR, Boolean.parseBoolean("true"));
     capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNHANDLED_PROMPT_BEHAVIOUR, Boolean.parseBoolean("false"));

Comment: Last try - `capabilities.setCapability("UNHANDLED_PROMPT_BEHAVIOUR", Boolean.valueOf("true"));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159548/discussion-between-priya-and-debanjanb).

Comment: Check out my updated Answer and let me know the status

Comment: Still I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Note :
FirefoxDriver(Capabilities desiredCapabilities), this constructor is Deprecated in selenium 3.141.0 (i am taking about 3.141.0 onwards)
so you can not pass Capabilities class object  to webDriver constructor. to pass Capabilities  functionality to webDriver constructor use FirefoxOptions class object and pass its object to WebDriver constructor.

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path-to gecko-driver");
driver.get("url");
Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();
 driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("username");
 driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("Pwd");
 driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
 driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```